# 404 error after migration of WP site

Tags: wordpress, http-status-code-404, database-migration

I have [this url](http://tacobell.royalworkshop.com), where I have my site now, but I migrate it to [this one](http://taco.royalworkshop.com). I have a custom permalink structure:

/%category%/%postname%/

In the [first link (old site)](http://tacobell.royalworkshop.com) al works fine, but in the new one, only the default option (?p=123) structure works.

It's important to say that the second link, the URL's points to another server, it means the second url is an CNAME in my server. I also import the .htaccess file.

How can I make work my custom structure in the new server?

Comment: Is the new server running on Apache with [`mod_rewrite`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) enabled? Is there anything added to the error logs when the server starts or when a problematic URL is visited (apart from a 404)?

Comment: who can I check it? the error logs just show me something like this:
[Tue Aug 02 19:03:48 2011] [error] [client 200.6.250.170] File does not exist: /var/www/html/menus, referer: http://taco.royalworkshop.com/

Comment: See ["how to enable mod_rewrite"](http://www.lavluda.com/2007/07/15/how-to-enable-mod_rewrite-in-apache22-debian/). If that doesn't work, could you post your .htaccess?

Comment: thanks! was an Apache AllowAll issue!

Comment: did you already solve the problem? i've got the same right now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*That did it for me:*

Try flushing your mod_rewrite rules:

Dashboard -> Settings -> Permalinks

Save settings (no need to make any changes)

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/14685/after-server-migration-only-the-homepage-works